# Compare the hours in Nifi is possible?

Tags: datetime, apache-nifi

My input contains dateTime with hours like below.,

```
1,23.01.2016 09:02:21,Mega,201
2,02.01.2016 10:02:23,Hema,202
```

Now i need to get 2nd Column [`"02.01.2016 10:02:23"`] and then compare it with current dateTime with milliseconds.

After that if 2nd Column is in between past 72 hours and then insert into sql server.

How can i compare hours in which data having with current datetime hours?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Your data appears to be in CSV format so you could attempt to extract the dateTime column from your file using the RouteOnContent processor and Regex, ***or*** you could convert your content into AVRO format, and then convert the AVRO into JSON and split the files so that you can extract dateTime individually as attributes.

Using your data as input you would:

- InferAvroSchema (assuming your layout above is standard)
- ConvertCSVToAvro (using the inferred schema)
- ConvertAvroToJSON
- SplitJSON
- EvaluateJSONPath (pull out the dateTime property and set as an attribute)
- RouteOnAttribute (compare the dateTime attribute to the system date you want)

System date - 72 hours can be calculated programmatically by using:

```
${now():toNumber():minus(259200000):format('dd.mm.yyyy hh:mm:ss')}
```

Comment: Your comprehensive option is really good; for the former, did you mean `RouteText`? `RouteOnContent` will send a copy of the whole flowfile to relationships where the regex matches, while `RouteText` evaluates each line individually.

Comment: Yes, good call. RouteText would be more appropriate on multi-line content.

Comment: @dgolf Thanks for your reply